# "Near Real Time" Request with JMS and Loose Coupling Architecture

Tags: performance, architecture, jms, soa, activemq-classic

I would like to use JMS and ActiveMQ (or any good JMS Broker) to enable loose coupling in my system.

In some cases a component of the system needs to access a service on another component, and the response need to be "Real Time" (for answering a request coming from a web application for example).

A way to do the request is to use a JMS queue. You may put several consumers and one will pick the message and execute the task. Then the response is sent back to the requesting component. It's good, it's loose coupled at some level and load balanced.

My question is about performance. Are there some figures on the performance level achieved by this architecture? Is it possible to achieve "Near Real Time", meaning that the cost implied by JMS should be under 5ms?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on so many factors that is really hard to say. I have tried on my machine, (will tell you the details of it if you need), to make a simple request, do some processing and return. I get less then 5ms right now. But that figure generally says nothing, because ActiveMQ is on my machine, the connection is really fast also, because it's all on localhost, etc etc.

What you want to do is simulate as much as possible your future architecture and try there. No one here is going to tell YES for sure or NO, well, because, it is impossible.

If you want "REAL TIME", then why would you introduce an asynchronous component in the first place?

Cheers,Eugene.

Comment: I don't really mean "Real Time" but rather SLA which may have to be provided on web services. An I wonder if it is achievable to respond in under few milliseconds. Then I just wonder if in this case it can be a viable solution. Regarding the asynchronous aspect, it's nt mandatory, I am just looking for loose coupling. I.e. I could expose a REST service on the depending module but in that case the depency becomes higher (too high IMO).

Comment: If I had to choose I would favor ActiveMQ over Web Services. Just that I played with it, worker with it, and placed it in production. There are ways to scale it, to cluster, to update, etc which are not possible with web services. I hope you choose right for you :)